# comparing the file names in same folder linux with different type(Extns)

Tags: shell, unix

I want to compare usr/folder1/*.java files and check if the .class file exists for all the JAVA files in same folder

Comment: provide some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is first get the java file list in the *.java directory
Then for every entry of *.java check it in class directory
Finally print the missing class files

You can do this using this code

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_DIR="Your java directory"
CLASS_DIR="Your class directory"

CUR_DIR=`pwd`

cd "${JAVA_DIR}"
JAVA_FILES=`ls *.java`

cd "${CLASS_DIR}"
MISS_FILES=""
for j_file in `echo "$JAVA_FILES" | tr ' ' '\n'`
do
    f_name=`echo $j_file | cut -d'.' -f1`
    c_name=$f_name".class"
    if [ ! -f $c_name ]
    then
        MISS_FILES="$MISS_FILES","$c_name"
    fi
done

cd "${CUR_DIR}"
echo "Following files are missing:$MISS_FILES"
```